# Runtime error when running my program

Tags: c, runtime-error

My code is to get the num of digits for any integer up to 1000000 at most. This is my code either using `while` or `for` or `if` :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h> 
int main() {
  int t,num_of_seven_segment=0;

  printf("Enter test case: ");

  scanf("%d", &t);`

 /* for(;t!=0;t=t/10)
  {
        if(t>=1000001)
break; 
      num_of_seven_segment++;
  }*/

  while(t!=0)
{
    t=t/10;
    num_of_seven_segment++;

  }
   printf(" %d",num_of_seven_segment);
   getch();

}
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#include <math.h>

int main()


{

int t;



int num_of_sevensegment=0;



printf("enter test cases");



scanf("%d",&t);




if(t<1000000)



num_of_sevensegment+=6;




 if (t<100000)



num_of_sevensegment--;




 if (t<10000)



num_of_sevensegment--;



 if (t<1000)



num_of_sevensegment--;


 if (t<100)


num_of_sevensegment--;



 if (t<10)



num_of_sevensegment--;



else if(t==1000000)



num_of_sevensegment=7;




printf("%d",num_of_sevensegment);




return 0;


}
```

Comment: so what is the problem you are facing exactly ? Tell us which input causes errors and so on

Comment: my problem is to get number of digits for any number, but the number must be at most 1000000, so the code excuted perfectly but when i had run time error  in online judge for my code and i don't know where is the problem either using while or for loop or using if also :(

Comment: Which code gives you runtime error? The first one or second one?

Comment: Try changing `int t,num_of_seven_segment=0;` to `int num_of_seven_segment=0; long t;` and `scanf("%d",&t);` to `scanf("%ld",&t);`

Comment: You should to tell us what the judging criteria are. For example, is handling invalid input part of the judging criteria? Because your code does not handle invalid input.

Comment: the first code using while or for gives me runtime error, the second code using if gives me (wrong code) on online judge except it excuted in dev c complier

Comment: You should fix the code formatting and at least include the problem statement and some sample data from the problem you're trying to solve if not a link to the problem itself.

Comment: I'd suggest a different approach. Set digits to 1 at the start and then have a while loop that runs while the value is > 10 or < -10, dividing the current value by 10 and increasing the digit count by 1 each time

Comment: read the value as a string instead (`strlen` gives then number of digits), then do an `atoi` on it, if `atoi` returns 0 its invalid number otherwise check range. also add a check for 0 also

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using an online judge, I would say that adding a `return 0;` statement at the end of the first code should fix it. `getch()` doesn't usually work.

Additionally (not really related to the runtime error), I don't think explicitly prompting the user for input is required in online judges.

Also, in the statement - `printf(" %d",num_of_seven_segment);` there seems to be an extra space before `%d` - a possible source of wrong answer.